# Cannot connect to 2G/3G networks using Android 11-based custom ROMs

Tags: custom-roms, mobile-network, android-11

I've tried Android 11-based ROMs, such as BlissROM, HavocOS, and crDroid, on Redmi 4X (santoni), but none of them could connect my phone to 2G (GSM) or 3G (WCDMA) networks. I've confirmed that the said networks are working in my area. However, they could connect to 4G (LTE) almost instantly. So, my phone is stuck with LTE network which is more battery draining and doesn't penetrate well inside the house.

There was one ROM (ReloadedOS, Android 10) that did manage to connect my phone to 2G which I confirmed by sending and receiving SMS messages and cellular calls. So, is this an inherent problem with Android 11-based ROMs?

Comment: Hi @Robert. As I've said in the post, I've tried using 2G (GSM only) in ReloadedOS, and I've confirmed that it works as I could send and receive SMS messages and cellular calls. So, the 2G network is still active in my country (Philippines).

Comment: don't use android 11, imho released too early. for issues with LineageOS better ask LineageOS support

Comment: Hi @alecxs. Are you suggesting that I try Android 10 ROMs instead? As for LOS, sadly, Redmi 4X (santoni) is no longer officially maintained.

Comment: \*#\*#4636#\*#\*

Comment: I've already accessed the Testing settings, but switching to "GSM only" leaves the Data and Voice Service to "Disconnected" and their types to "Unknown". However, when I select "LTE only", it instantly connects to the right Service and Type.